# Count occurrences of item in JSON element grouped by another element

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of occurences of an item (Activity) in a json file grouped by another item (Source). Example json below.

```
{
    "No": "9",
    "Time": "08:12",
    "Source": "location1",
    "Dest": "location3",
    "Activity": "fast"
}
```

My code below so far counts the occurences of each Activity

```
from collections import Counter
import json

with open('dataset_3.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)  # loads json data
    c = Counter(item['Activity'] for item in json_data)
    print(c)
```

The code correctly counts and outputs below.

Counter({'fast': 8, 'medium': 1, 'slow': 1})

I would like now to count each occurence of activity again, but grouped by location so the output should be something like:

location 1  Fast: 8, Medium: 1, Slow: 2

loctaion 2  Fast: 6, Medium: 3, Slow: 4

I have tried the code below but the output is not correct (see below)

```
with open('dataset_3.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)  # loads json data
    for item in json_data:
        if item['Source'] == 'location1':
            c = Counter(item['Activity'])
            print(c)
```

Output

```
Counter({'f': 3, 'a': 1, 's': 1, 't'})
Counter({'s': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'w'})
```

Comment: Could you do an `if` with your generator in the first code example you had such as: `c = Counter(item['Activity'] for item in json_data if item['Source'] == 'location1')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and yes that did the trick and returned exactly what I wanted !   How do I accept that answer ?

Comment: I'll put it as an answer for future reference then.

Comment: haha you answered my question before i even asked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an `if` inside the generator statement for the `Counter` to add a condition to the `for` loop. I pasted your code with the fix below:

```
from collections import Counter
import json

with open('dataset_3.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)  # loads json data
    c = Counter(item['Activity'] for item in json_data if item['Source'] == 'location1')
    print(c)
```